# How do you make an IIFE remember **each** instance of a variable when dealing with event listeners?

Tags: javascript, iife

I'm working with a list of images that may change in number, so fixed IDs and event listeners are not practical. The below code produces the correct number of buttons with the correct IDs, but only the last one has a functional event listener.

```
for (var i = 0; i < amount; i++) {
    !function(index) {

        if (items[index].classList.contains('current')) {
            document.getElementById('selectButtons').innerHTML += '<button id=\"bitems' + index + '\"> ⬤ <span class=\"offscreen\">Item ' + i + '</span></button>';
        } 
        else
        {
            document.getElementById('selectButtons').innerHTML += '<button id=\"bitems' + index + '\"> ◯ <span class=\"offscreen\">Item ' + i + '</span></button>';
        }

        document.getElementById('bitems' + index).addEventListener("click", function(ev) {
        alert("clicked");
        });

    }(i);
}
```

Apparently the IIFE is not storing the individual variables like it is supposed to, but I can't figure out why. After all, that is the entire purpose of an IIFE within a loop.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIFE is working fine.  Actually every time you update the innerHTML for selectButtons, the DOM is recreated, and all the events attached to it are gone!

Instead of updating the innerHTML in each iteration, you can append the buttons to it instead like:

```
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  !function(index) {
    var button = document.createElement("BUTTON");
    var t = document.createTextNode("Button" + index);
    button.appendChild(t);
    document.getElementById('selectButtons').appendChild(button);

    button.addEventListener("click", function(ev) {
      alert("clicked +" +index);
    });

  }(i);
}
```

Please do add the conditions around it that you need.

Comment: I just noticed this didn't address the ID issue, but that was simple enough. Here's the code for anyone wrangling a similar issue: `    var att = document.createAttribute("id");
    att.value = "bitems" + i;
    button.setAttributeNode(att);`

Answer (score 1):

Every time you do `innerHTML +=` you are replacing the entire HTML, which removes any previously installed event handlers. This is one perfectly good reason not to treat HTML as a bunch of strings that you `innerHTML` onto the page. Instead of strings, think in terms of elements, as in another answer. Then you also don't need to use IDs as a poor man's "variable name" to reference elements; you can just use the element itself.

You don't need a clumsy IIFE. That's what `let` is for.

Here's a cleaned-up version of your code:

```
var buttons = document.getElementById('selectButtons');

for (let i = 0; i < amount; i++) {
  var current = items[i].classList.contains('current');
  var button = document.createElement("BUTTON");
  var bullet = document.createTextNode(current ? '◯' : '⬤')
  var span = document.createElement('span');
  van spanText = `Item ${i}`;

  span.className = 'offscreen';
  span.appendChild(spanText);
  button.appendChild(bullet);
  button.appendChild(span);
  buttons.appendChild(button);

  button.addEventListener('click', () => alert(`clicked ${i}`));
}
```

If you want to save a line or two, you could take advantage of the fact that `appendChild` returns the appended child, and chain:

```
buttons.appendChild(button).appendChild(span).appendChild(spanText);
```

If you're going to be doing a lot of this, it would be best to create some tiny utility routines:

```
function createElementWithText(tag, text) {
  var b = document.createElement(tag);
  var t = document.createTextNode(text);

  b.appendChild(t);
  return b;
}

function button(text) { return createElementWithText('button', text); }
function span(text)   { return createElementWithText('span', text); }
```

Now you can write your code more concisely as:

```
var buttons = document.getElementById('selectButtons');

for (let i = 0; i < amount; i++) {
  var current = items[i].classList.contains('current');
  var button  = button(current ? '◯' : '⬤');
  var span    = span(`Item ${i}`);

  span.className = 'offscreen';
  buttons.appendChild(button).appendChild(span);

  button.addEventListener('click', () => alert(`clicked ${i}`));
}
```

Actually, it would moderately preferable to create a **document fragment**, add all the buttons to it in advance, then insert it into the DOM a single time.

However, in practice, you would be better off using some kind of templating language, in which you could write something like:

```
<div id="selectButtons">
  {{for i upto amount}}
    <button {{listen 'click' clicked}}>
      {{if items[i] hasClass 'current'}}◯{{else}}⬤{{endIf}}
      <span class="offscreen">Index {{i}}</span>
    </button>
  {{endFor}}
</div>
```

It's beyond the scope of this answer to recommend a particular templating language. There are many good ones out there, such as Mustache, that google can help you find, with a search such as "javascript templating languages".